# In Rust, how to use `find()` on a `iter_mut`

Tags: rust

How can I make this compile:

```
struct S {
    s:String
}

fn main() {
    let mut v:Vec<S>;
    let cmp = "asdf";
    v.iter_mut().find(|&&x| x == cmp);
    //                 ^^^
    //                 What to write here when using find on a iter_mut (and why?)
}
```

Error message:

```
 --> src/main.rs:8:25
  |
8 |     v.iter_mut().find(|&&x| x == cmp);
  |                         ^-
  |                         ||
  |                         |expected due to this
  |                         types differ in mutability
  |                         help: you can probably remove the explicit borrow: `x`
  |
  = note: expected mutable reference `&mut S`
                     found reference `&_`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
error: could not compile `asdf` due to previous error
```

Comment: have you tried `&mut S` following compiler suggestion?

Comment: Yes, I have tried `&mut S`, `&&mut S` and several other...

Comment: You are overthinking this: `find(|x| x.s == cmp)`. The compiler will take care of autoref/deref to do the field access and autoref the `String`-field to a `str` to call `PartialEq`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to [destructure](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/flow_control/match/destructuring.html) S in the closure because that would move the String.

```rust
struct S {
    s: String,
}

fn main() {
    let mut v: Vec<_> = vec![S { s: "Hello".into() }, S { s: "asdf".into() }];
    let cmp = "asdf";

    // Will be Option<&mut S>
    let _found = v.iter_mut().find(|x| x.s == cmp);
}
```

I added two items to the Vec since you declared v without defining it. Notice that the closure just takes `x` which is a `&&mut`, but you don't have to explicitly say that anywhere because `x` will be dereferenced in the body of the closure.

The expression `x.s == cmp` compares the `String`, `s`, from to the `&str`, `cmp`.

```rust
// Automatically dereferenced
x.s == cmp
```

And manually:

```rust
// Manually dereferenced. You don't have to do this for structs.
(**x).s
```

### Further reading

- [Destructuring](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/flow_control/match/destructuring.html)
- [Dereferencing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28519997/what-are-rusts-exact-auto-dereferencing-rules)
- [PartialEq](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.PartialEq.html)